# How to append the id to the url after assigning the id to the String

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

Scenario: I need to append the id to the url.

What I have done :
I have taken the last id from the table and stored it in a list:

Then I get the text of the id and is Stored in a `String`.

```java
List<WebElement> id = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//table[contains(@class,'mat-table')]//tr/td[1])[last()]"));

int rowsize = id.size();

for(int i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
{

    String text = id.get(i).getText();

    System.out.println("Get the id:"+text);
```

Then I use that text and append it to the URL

`String confirmationURL = "https://test-websites.net/#/email?type=confirm";`

`String newurl = confirmationURL+"&id=text";`  = **This part iam giving the text as id ... which is

wrong and I need to enter the id which I got from the list ....**

```java
driver.get(newurl);
```

So Basically the url should be like: `https://test-websites.net /#/email?type=confirm&id=47474`

Can someone pls give inputs on what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new list of URLS, and can use `add` method to append text.

```
List<WebElement> id = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//table[contains(@class,'mat-table')]//tr/td[1])[last()]"));
String confirmationURL = "https://test-websites.net/#/email?type=confirm";
List<String> newurls = new ArrayList<String>();

int rowsize = id.size();

for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++) {
    String text = id.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("Get the id:"+text);
    newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + text);
}
```

after successfully execution of this code, you'd have a `newurls` list with URLs ending with id's from `//table[contains(@class,'mat-table')]//tr/td[1])[last()]` xpath.

Comment: thanks for the input after i append the id to newurls how do i go to the url ... it should be assigned to a string and then i should go to the url ... driver.get(url)...can you pls give inputs on this

Comment: okay why not ` driver.get(newurls.get(0));`  or `driver.get(newurls.get(1));`, I think this should work for you.